# How to insert list of words inside particular regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex

```py
import re
text = """STAR PLUS LIMITED Unit B & C, 15/F, Casey Aberdeen House, 38 Heung Yip Road, Wong Chuk Hang, Hong Kong. Tel: (852)2511 0112 Fax: 2507 4300 Email: info@starplushk.com Ref No: LSM25781 SALES Sales Quote No: SP21-SQ10452 Buyer's Ref: LSM-021042-5 Messers JSC "Tander" Russian Federation 350002 Krasnodar"""
             
ref_no = re.findall(r"(?:(?<=Buyer's Ref: )|(?<=Ref No: ))[\w\d-]+",text)
print(ref_no)
```

Required solution: `['LSM25781', 'LSM-021042-5']`
The script above outputs this, but I have man keywords, so I want to generate the regex dynamically. How can I do that?

Tried:

```py
ref_keywords = ["Buyer's Ref:","Ref No:","Reference number:"]
b = r"(?:(?<=" + '|'.join(ref_keyword)+ r" ))[\w\d-]+"
ref_no = re.findall(b, text)
print(ref_no)
```

This results in the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/v/.config/JetBrains/PyCharm2021.3/scratches/scratch_2.py", line 7, in <module>
    ref_no = re.findall(regex, text)
  File "/home/v/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/lib/python3.9/re.py", line 241, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
  File "/home/v/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/lib/python3.9/re.py", line 304, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/home/v/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/lib/python3.9/sre_compile.py", line 768, in compile
    code = _code(p, flags)
  File "/home/v/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/lib/python3.9/sre_compile.py", line 607, in _code
    _compile(code, p.data, flags)
  File "/home/v/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/lib/python3.9/sre_compile.py", line 182, in _compile
    raise error("look-behind requires fixed-width pattern")
re.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Is there a solution to add list of keywords inside regex. I cannot use "|" because I have many list of keywords.

Answer (score 0):

```
key_word = ['key1', 'key2', 'key2']
combined_word = ""
for key in key_word:
  combined_word += "|"+key

import re
sentence = "I wana delete key1 and key2 but also key3."
re.split(combined_word, sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the following way (you almost had it, you just need to create all the regex characters for each keyword:

```py
import re

text = """STAR PLUS LIMITED Unit B & C, 15/F, Casey Aberdeen House, 38 Heung Yip Road, Wong Chuk Hang, Hong Kong. Tel: (852)2511 0112 Fax: 2507 4300 Email: info@starplushk.com Ref No: LSM25781 SALES Sales Quote No: SP21-SQ10452 Buyer's Ref: LSM-021042-5 Messers JSC "Tander" Russian Federation 350002 Krasnodar"""

ref_keywords = ["Buyer's Ref:", "Ref No:", "Reference number:"]


def keyword_to_regex(keyword: str) -> str:
    # you missed creating these for each keyword
    return f"(?<={keyword} )"


regex_for_all_keywords = r"(?:" + "|".join(map(keyword_to_regex, ref_keywords)) + r")[\w\d-]+"

ref_no = re.findall(regex_for_all_keywords, text)
print(ref_no)  # ['LSM25781', 'LSM-021042-5']
```